# Custom start point for axis labels in echart

Tags: echarts

I have a chart where I've spaced the x-axis labels three months apart. However, I would like that pattern to start in January so that the labels are January [year], April [year], July [year], October [year], etc. How do I define the start point for the labels (not the axis itself)? I have looked through the documentation but didn't have any luck finding a solution.

Here is the code for the [chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjIaY.png).

```
option = {
  "yAxis": [
    {
      "show": true
    }
  ],
  "xAxis": [
    {
      "data": ["2017-06-01", "2017-07-01", "2017-08-01", "2017-09-01", "2017-10-01", "2017-11-01", "2017-12-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-02-01", "2018-03-01", "2018-04-01", "2018-05-01", "2018-06-01", "2018-07-01", "2018-08-01", "2018-09-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-11-01", "2018-12-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-08-01", "2019-09-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01"],
      "type": "time",
      "boundaryGap": true,
      //min: 1496323473000,
      maxInterval: 7776000000,
      minInterval: 7776000000,
      "axisLabel": {
        rotate: 90,
        formatter: function (value) { 
            var d = new Date(value); 
            var months = ['Jan', "/Feb/", "/Mar/", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
            return (months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear());}
      }
    }
  ],
  "legend": {
    "data": [
      "Category 1",
      "Category 2",
      "Category 3",
      "Category 4",
      "Category 5"
    ]
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "value": ["2017-06-01", " 62"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-07-01", " 66"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-08-01", " 55"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-09-01", " 58"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-10-01", " 47"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-11-01", "196"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-12-01", "161"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-01-01", " 53"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-02-01", " 28"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-03-01", " 24"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-04-01", " 38"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-05-01", " 49"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-06-01", " 45"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-07-01", " 41"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-08-01", " 60"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-09-01", " 40"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-10-01", " 49"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-11-01", "206"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-12-01", "167"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-01-01", " 60"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-02-01", " 38"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-03-01", " 44"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-04-01", " 43"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-05-01", " 50"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-06-01", " 58"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-07-01", " 60"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-08-01", " 49"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-09-01", " 63"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-10-01", " 50"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-11-01", "155"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-12-01", "180"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2020-01-01", " 77"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2020-02-01", " 47"]
        }
      ],
      "yAxisIndex": 0,
      "xAxisIndex": 0,
      "name": "Category 1",
      "type": "line",
      "coordinateSystem": "cartesian2d"
    },
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "value": ["2017-06-01", "11"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-07-01", " 7"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-08-01", " 5"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-09-01", " 6"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-10-01", " 9"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-11-01", "33"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-12-01", "42"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-01-01", " 6"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-02-01", " 3"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-03-01", " 3"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-04-01", " 6"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-05-01", "10"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-06-01", " 4"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-07-01", "11"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-08-01", " 7"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-09-01", " 2"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-10-01", " 7"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-11-01", "36"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-12-01", "28"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-01-01", " 9"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-02-01", " 9"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-03-01", " 8"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-04-01", " 7"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-05-01", " 6"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-06-01", " 6"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-07-01", " 5"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-08-01", " 4"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-09-01", " 5"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-10-01", " 8"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-11-01", "15"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-12-01", "24"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2020-01-01", "10"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2020-02-01", " 6"]
        }
      ],
      "yAxisIndex": 0,
      "xAxisIndex": 0,
      "name": "Category 2",
      "type": "line",
      "coordinateSystem": "cartesian2d"
    },
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "value": ["2017-06-01", "149"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-07-01", "158"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-08-01", "142"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-09-01", "133"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-10-01", "129"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-11-01", "693"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-12-01", "680"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-01-01", "189"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-02-01", "103"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-03-01", " 97"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-04-01", "103"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-05-01", "117"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-06-01", "146"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-07-01", "138"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-08-01", "144"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-09-01", "137"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-10-01", "140"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-11-01", "611"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-12-01", "722"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-01-01", "195"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-02-01", "124"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-03-01", "124"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-04-01", "127"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-05-01", "140"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-06-01", "169"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-07-01", "176"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-08-01", "132"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-09-01", "126"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-10-01", "128"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-11-01", "325"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-12-01", "516"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2020-01-01", "257"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2020-02-01", "118"]
        }
      ],
      "yAxisIndex": 0,
      "xAxisIndex": 0,
      "name": "Category 3",
      "type": "line",
      "coordinateSystem": "cartesian2d"
    },
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "value": ["2017-06-01", "10"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-07-01", " 8"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-08-01", " 8"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-09-01", "10"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-10-01", " 4"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-11-01", "66"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-12-01", "66"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-01-01", "11"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-02-01", "10"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-03-01", " 3"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-04-01", " 5"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-05-01", " 9"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-06-01", "16"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-07-01", " 3"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-08-01", "11"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-09-01", "13"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-10-01", "12"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-11-01", "52"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-12-01", "60"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-01-01", "19"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-02-01", " 9"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-03-01", " 5"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-04-01", " 6"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-05-01", "12"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-06-01", "11"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-07-01", "11"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-08-01", " 8"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-09-01", " 9"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-10-01", " 5"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-11-01", "23"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-12-01", "32"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2020-01-01", "18"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2020-02-01", "15"]
        }
      ],
      "yAxisIndex": 0,
      "xAxisIndex": 0,
      "name": "Category 4",
      "type": "line",
      "coordinateSystem": "cartesian2d"
    },
    {
      "data": [
        {
          "value": ["2017-06-01", "19"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-07-01", "25"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-08-01", "11"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-09-01", "19"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-10-01", "21"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-11-01", "42"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2017-12-01", "45"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-01-01", "21"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-02-01", "11"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-03-01", "15"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-04-01", "19"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-05-01", "24"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-06-01", "28"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-07-01", "24"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-08-01", "26"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-09-01", "26"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-10-01", "20"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-11-01", "65"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2018-12-01", "82"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-01-01", "39"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-02-01", "19"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-03-01", "30"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-04-01", "24"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-05-01", "35"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-06-01", "35"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-07-01", "45"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-08-01", "38"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-09-01", "26"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-10-01", "19"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-11-01", "65"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2019-12-01", "85"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2020-01-01", "44"]
        },
        {
          "value": ["2020-02-01", "28"]
        }
      ],
      "yAxisIndex": 0,
      "xAxisIndex": 0,
      "name": "Category 5",
      "type": "line",
      "coordinateSystem": "cartesian2d"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show empty interval from January to June just add to xAxis option `min: '2017-01-01'`

[image]

Comment: That's not what I'm after. I want the labels to always show on January, April, July, and October (beginning of quarters), regardless of where the chart starts.